# Laravel error: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::show does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

When calling a Controller function, in a Laravel 5.6 blade/view, I get the following error message.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::show does not exist

I can't find where the error or the source of this error is. I read dozens of posts here with the same error, but none of them were related to code/context/type of models/controllers(...) that I have.

Blade view where the error message is shown.

**Blade**

```php
@foreach (\App\Portfolio::show() as $port)
    <option value="{{$port->id_portfolio}}">{{$port->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```php
class PortfolioController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $portfolio = \App\Portfolio::where([
            ['flg_active', '=', true],
            ['id_user', '=', Auth::user()->id]
        ])->get();

        return $portfolio;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```php
class Portfolio extends Model
{
    public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'id_portfolio', 'id_portfolio');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id_user', 'id');
    }
}
```

Test with all() instead of show(), and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Blade** you call the model. 
And the method you need is in the controller PortfolioController

**PortfolioController**

```
public static function show()
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach (\App\PortfolioController ::show() as $port)
   <option value="{{$port->id_portfolio}}">{{$port->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```